# What is the relation between all those MS Azure Terms and Structures?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Currently i am trying to dig deeper into the organizational/entity structure of ms azure. All I find online in discussions and official ms documentation only shows parts of the bigger picture but never the underlying relationships between them.

I try to formulate statements which I ask you to correct in case they are wrong:

1. I log in to the azure portal using an email adress witch is called **account**
2. In the azure portal *I am acting in the context of* a **directory**
3. The **account** i use to log in *is associated with* an **identity** in the directory
4. A **directory** *belongs* to a **tenant**
5. Signing up for MS Azure using my **Microsoft Account** will create a **Tenant**
6. A **Subscription** I create *is assoiciated with* but *not created/stored within* a **directory** (not with a **tenant**)
7. A **Subscription** I create is *associated with* the **Account** I am currently logged in, called **Azure Account**
8. A **Management Group** will be created within the directory per default, called **Root Management Group**
9. When no other Management Group is created, all **Subscriptions** I create are *associated with* this **Root Management Group**

Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks TGY for your question. The terms "tenant" and "directory" are for the most part interchangeable and are used in Azure.

A tenant is an instance of an Azure Active Directory. The tenant is an account in Azure that comes with a subdomain and an associated Azure Active Directory. In order to use an Azure Active Directory you need to become a tenant within the system. So a tenant is basically securing a .onmicrosoft.com subdomain. At that point you would have one account registered in your Azure AD.

An Azure subscription is a logical container used to provision resources in Azure.It serves as a single billing unit for Azure resources in that services used in Azure are billed to a subscription. An Azure subscription is linked to a single account, but you can add multiple subscriptions to the same directory.

Please see this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/enterprise-scale/management-group-and-subscription-organization) if it helps you.

Root Management>>Management Group>>Subscription>>Resources Group>>Resources. So for IAM(Identity & Access Management) purpose, management Group is higher level than Subscription. Subscription is higher than Resource Group and Resource Group is higher than a particular resource level.

Please find below Architectural structure for more understanding and pictorial representation --
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts and the explanation. The account term is very confusing since its used interchangeable by most of the people for tenant, directory. On top of that there is an ad-account, microsoft-account ...